If $\sum_ix_i=1,\sum_i x_i^2=1,\sum_ix_i^3=1$, then $\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}=\{1,0,...,0\}$
Suppose $x_i\in\mathbb{R}$ for $1\leq i\leq n$, $x_1\geq x_2\geq ... \geq x_n$. Prove that if $\sum_ix_i=1,\sum_i x_i^2=1,\sum_ix_i^3=1$, then $\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}=\{1,0,...,0\}$.
From Newton's Identity we have $e_2=e_3=0$, it suffices to show that $p_4=1$ or $e_4=0$. Because if $p_4=1$ we have $\sum_{i\neq j}x_i^2x_j^2=0$ but I don't know how to prove it.

From $\sum_i x_i^2=1$, we know that $|x_i|\le 1$. Therefore
$$1=|\sum_i x_i^3|\le \sum_i |x_i^3| = \sum_i |x_i^2||x_i| \le \sum_i |x_i^2| = 1$$
For equality to hold, we must have $|x_i^2|=|x_i^2||x_i|$ for all $i$, hence $x_i=0, \pm 1$. Now from $\sum_i x_i^2=1$, it's clear that only one of them can be $\pm 1$, and from $\sum_i x_i^3=1$, it's clear that the nonzero one has to be $1$, not $-1$.
$\sum_{i} x_i = 1$ is redundant.

A little step is missing. From your reasoning, there is only one  nonzero $x_i = 1$ but that could be on any position.  You need to say that from the question, $x_1\geq x_2\geq ... \geq x_n$, which has the consequence that actually this position is fixed to $x_1 = 1$. Also, for equality to hold, you have to establish that $|\sum_i x_i^3|= \sum_i |x_i^3| $, which follows from $x_i=0, + 1$.

Since this is tagged linear-algebra, I'll give a proof in that vein.  Zero's do not affect the power sums so we can make the argument on $\big\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\big\}$ by looking at $\big\{x_1,\cdots,x_n, 0\big\}$.  Define $r:= n+1$ and let $D$ be an $r\times r$ diagonal matrix with $d_{i,i}:=x_i$ (which means $d_{r,r}=0$).  With $w_1, w_2, w_3:= I_{r^2}, D, D^2$, and $S:=\Big\{w_4,\cdots,w_{\frac{r(r+1)}{2}}\Big\}$ containing arbitrary elements of $W$, the vector (sub)space of $r\times r$ real symmetric matrices.
Let $G$ be a Gram type matrix with $g_{i,j}:= \langle g_i,g_j\rangle =\text{trace}\big(g_i g_j\big)-\text{trace}\big(g_i\big)\text{trace}\big(g_j\big)$.  The leading $3\times 3$ principal submatrix is $ \left[\begin{matrix}r -r^2 & 1 -r &1-r \\1-r  & 0 &0 \\ 1-r &0& \alpha \end{matrix}\right]$ where $\alpha \leq 0$ (why?).
This matrix has negative trace and a determinant of $-a(r-1)^2 \geq 0$ hence (at least) $2$ eigenvalues $\leq 0$.
Cauchy Interlacing tells us that $G$ has at least two eigenvalues $\leq 0$ but the bilinear form  $\langle, \rangle$ is non-degenerate on $W$ with signature $\big(\frac{m(m+1)}{2}-1,1\big)$, ref Finding the rank and signature of $\phi = tr (A B) - tr(A)tr(B)$. Conclude: at least one vector in $\big\{w_1,w_2,w_3\big\} \bigcup S$ must be linearly dependent and since $S$ was arbitrary, we know $\big\{w_1,w_2,w_3\big\}=\big\{I_r,D,D^2\big\}$ is linearly dependent $\implies D$ has a minimal polynomial $p(z)=z\cdot(z-\lambda)$. Revisiting the power sums reads $m\cdot \lambda=\sum_{k=1}^n x_i = 1 = \sum_{k=1}^n x_i^2 =m\cdot \lambda^2=\big(\sum_{k=1}^n x_i\big)^2 = m^2\cdot \lambda^2\implies m=1\implies \lambda =1$
